# Can't set innerHTML of td on IE Mobile 6

Tags: javascript, html, windows-ce, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to dynamically create a table in IE6 Mobile (yes, I know, but we're dealing with Motorola hand scanners and that's what they run) and I'm having trouble actually adding data to the `<td>`'s.  I've tried a number of methods, all of which result in the error `Object doesn't support this property or method`.

A couple of things I've tried, as well as the line that throws the error:

```
        ...
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = 'test'; // error, also tried innerText
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  table.appendChild(tbody)
}
```

Without the line with the error, this all works.

I've also tried:

```
        ...
        var td = document.createElement('td');
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode('test')); // error
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  table.appendChild(tbody)
}
```

And:

```
        ...
        var td = document.createElement('td');

        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = 'test'; // also tried innerText and createTextNode
                                 // approach like example no. 2

        td.appendChild(span)
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  }
  table.appendChild(tbody)
}
```

And, it *might* go without saying, but, all of these methods work in all browsers I've tested on my PC, including IE5 mode from the IE developer tools.

Comment: What if you manually built the html? tr.appendChild("<td>test</td>");

Comment: Have you tried jQuery in hopes that it will handle the oddities?

Comment: What is the JavaScript error that you are getting? Have you tried appending the `<td>` first, then setting the `innerHTML`?

Comment: Charlie, I'll try that.  And @ShawnJacobson, I have, and, unfortunately, jQuery just totally did not work on these devices.

Comment: If you are only adding text, like your example shows, have you tried using innerText instead of innerHTML?

Comment: Yeah, that's mentioned in the comments in the examples

Comment: What about using the insertCell method on the tr?  Sorry for throwing out guesses, but without access to Mobile IE6, that's what most of us will be left with.

Comment: @ShawnJacobson, totally understood and expected, came here just looking for ideas that I hadn't tried.  `row.insertCell` is now giving the same error, `*Object doesn't support this property or method*`. And, to confirm, `row`/`tr` are in fact objects at the time of execution, these aren't just being thrown because the objects are `undefined`.

Comment: jQuery never supported IE Mobile, the breakages are far too bad to work around. IE Mobile 6.0's standards support lies somewhere between IE3 and IE4. Large parts of basic JavaScript and DOM Level 0 (indeed, including `insertCell`) are just completely missing. IIRC I had to create a whole table in a single div's innerHTML because I couldn't alter anything more fine-grained than that. @Tom I am sorry you have to work with this vile throwback of a browser

Comment: @bobince, thanks for that, good to know about where IE Mobile 6.0 stands in terms of support.  Guess that's the convincing it takes to just go ahead and build up the table in a huge string and `.innerHTML` it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling it is a name collision on the page. Change the variable names.

```
    ...
    var tdx = document.createElement('td');
    tdx.innerHTML = 'test';
  }
  tr.appendChild(tdx);
  ...
```

Comment: I actually had previously tried this as well -- just tried again and same issue.  Thanks for the suggestion, though